# How to bound QString to QSqlQuery that call procedure which output varchar?

Tags: c++, sql-server, qt

I managed to bound integer values to this type of queries but I couldn't manage to bound QString.

I keep getting empty QVariant. However, in Sql server I get the value I wanted to get.

The procedure will output VARCHAR(max)

```
qDebug() << query.prepare("{call dbo.p_test(?)}");
query.bindValue(0, QString(""), QSql::Out);
qDebug() << query.exec();
qDebug() << query.boundValue(0);
```

I have tried binding:

```
''
""
QString()
QString("")
QVariant()
QVariant(QVariant::String)
```

**How I should bind the value to be able to bound correctly?**

I am using Qt 4.8.4

P.S. When doing it this way I can get the string value I wanted.

```
query.exec("DECLARE @r VARCHAR(MAX); EXEC dbo.p_test @r OUTPUT; SELECT @r");
query.first();
qDebug()<<query.value(0);
```

**updates**

Here how it gets really weirdo

1. I changed `QSql::Out` to `QSql::InOut`.
2. I edited the procedure so it will insert the value in a table.
3. I changed the bind command to `query.bindValue(0, QString("1234567"), QSql::InOut);`

I checked for the value I had passed in sql server and it was

> '1234567'

I checked the value I got from `qDebug()<<query.boundValue(0)` and it was

> QVariant(QString, "1234")

no matter that my procedure should return

> '7654321'

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.p_test
    @rez varchar(max)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test VALUES(@rez)
    SET @rez = '7654321';
END;
```

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using in this example?

Comment: I have checked for them despite of I do only one bind, they are all empty **QVariant(, )**

Comment: I really think the problem is in encoding, from sql server to the Qt driver.
it looks like that sql server transform the varchar to 2 bytes each and uses the original size of binded value.

Comment: Whats your Driver/ Databse ? Qt supports SPs differently for different drivers.

Comment: @MohammadKanan QODBC / Sql Server 2012, can you explain what is SPs?

Comment: with QODBC/sql server you have to set `query.setForwardOnly(true);` , SP: stored procedure

Comment: It made no difference. Everything is the same with all types that QVariant can have and be used to store a string.

Comment: For SQL Server [Qt ODBC Stored Procedure Support](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#qodbc), for MySQL [QMYSQL Stored Procedure Support](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#qmysql)

Comment: See the limitations/incomplete support for each in those links

Comment: My main problem is in getting the string value, it is really intresting why I can pass the string using `QSql::InOut`, I change the value in the procedure, but bound will give me about the half of the string that I have passed!!!, with integers I don't have any problem

Comment: Thank you. I already read this link 6 times. setForwardOnly is important when using sets as a return value. My procedure returns a string (varchar or nvarchar). I will check for recompiling the driver on holidays and give feedback

Comment: I think that single returned string is also a _result set_. anyway Qt query binding .. I know it has a lot of issues.

Comment: I have just tested an exampe using Qt 5.9.2, everything worked like a charm, I can get the value which I output in the prcedure. the major difference between Qt4 and Qt5 is unicode by defualt. So will try my hard to find out the problem, mainly by recompiling plugin, secondry analyzing sources.

Comment: This bug is present in Qt4 and is fixed in Qt5 (hence my question): https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-18435

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments

> This bug is present in Qt4 and is fixed in Qt5 (hence my question): bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-18435 – jbh Mar 27 at 9:54

it is really a bug, no way to get around it in Qt4.

Qt4 is too buggy, I have found another 3 bugs today -_- unlucky me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to properly format the output,

```
qDebug() << query.boundValue(0).toString();
```

or:

```
qDebug() << query.boundValue(0).toString().toUtf8().data();
```

if you have more than bounded values, then you can use `QSqlQuery::boundValues()`  with a list:

```
list.at(i).toString().toUtf8().data()
```

Comment: Thank you Mohammad, but it is not related to the problem. it is really weird problem. I am going to add more details on it.